# How to set up XAML ListView and create buttons to update a value

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

First off, apologies if this question doesn't make perfect sense - I am a complete newbie when it comes to C# and XAML.

I have a created this class of people:

```
class Student
{
    private string studentID;
    public string StudentID
    {
        get { return studentID; }
        set
        {
            studentID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StudentID");
        }
    }

    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    private string surname;
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname; }
        set
        {
            surname = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Surname");
        }
    }

    private string group;
    public string Group
    {
        get { return group; }
        set
        {
            group = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Group");
        }
    }

    private int cValue;
    public int CValue
    {
        get { return cValue; }
        set
        {
            cValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CValue");
        }
    }

    private string teacher;
    public string Teacher
    {
        get { return teacher; }
        set
        {
            teacher = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Teacher");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }

    public Student() { }

    public Student(string studentID, string firstName, string surname, string group, int cValue, string teacher)
    {
        StudentID = studentID;
        FirstName = firstName;
        Surname = surname;
        Group = group;
        CValue = cValue;
        Teacher = teacher;
    }


    // strings used to create random students
    private static readonly string[] firstNames = { "Adam", "Bob", "Carl", "David", "Edgar", "Frank", "George", "Harry", "Isaac", "Jesse", "Ken", "Larry" };
    private static readonly string[] surnames = { "Adamson", "Bobson", "Carlson", "Davidson", "Edgarson", "Frankson", "Georgeson", "Harryson", "Isaacson", "Jesseson", "Kenson", "Larryson" };
    private static readonly string[] groups = { "6a", "5b" };
    private static readonly string[] teachers = { "Fred", "Jim"};

    // method to create random students
    public static IEnumerable<Student> CreateStudents(int count)
    {
        var people = new List<Student>();

        var r = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i< count; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("A");
            builder.Append(i.ToString());
            string num = builder.ToString();
            var s = new Student()
            {
                StudentID = num,
                FirstName = firstNames[r.Next(firstNames.Length)],
                Surname = surnames[r.Next(surnames.Length)],
                Group = groups[r.Next(groups.Length)],
                Teacher = teachers[r.Next(teachers.Length)]
            };
            people.Add(s);
        }
        return people;
    }

}
```

I have then created a list of these people objects, and I can bind this list to a list/grid view easily enough.

What I want to do though is have a plus and minus button **on each item** to add or take away 1 from that persons CValue. (I would upload a picture to demonstrate, but SO won't let me...)

How could I lay out the XAML and add bindings for this in a way that even an idiot like me can understand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand` on your Student VM. They are not part of WPF, but are both commonly used implementations of `ICommand` that invoke a delegate directly in your VM and are used extensively in MVVM. You can then bind your buttons `Command` directly to them:

```
class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ICommand AddCommand    { get; private set; }
    ICommand RemoveCommand { get; private set; }

    public Student()
    {
        this.AddCommand = new RelayCommand(Add);
        this.RemoveCommand = new RelayCommand(Remove);
    }

    private Add()
    {
        this.CValue++;
    }

    private Remove()
    {
        this.CValue--;
    }

    //snip rest of Student properties
}
```

And in your XAML student template:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddCommand>" Content="Add"/>
<Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand>" Content="Remove"/>
```

If you prefer to keep your Student object free from VM stuff (ie it's purely a model class), then you can implement the same commands on your parent VM, but pass the student object as the command parameter:

```
class StudentsVM: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ICommand AddCommand    { get; private set; }
    ICommand RemoveCommand { get; private set; }

    public StudentsVM()
    {
        this.AddCommand = new RelayCommand<Student>(Add);
        this.RemoveCommand = new RelayCommand<Student>(Remove);
    }

    private Add(Student student)
    {
        student.CValue++;
    }

    private Remove(Student student)
    {
        student.CValue--;
    }

    //snip rest of Student properties
}
```

And in your XAML student template:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AddCommand, ElementName=root}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        Content="Add"/>
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveCommand, ElementName=root}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        Content="Remove"/>
```

Where "root" is your parent view. This is just one way of getting hold of the commands in the parent view, you could use RelativeSource instead if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

As u can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the PropertyChanged event is an interface event of INotifyPropertyChanged, so I think your class 'Student' needs to explicitly implement this interface.

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Maybe [this](http://justinangel.net/automagicallyimplementinginotifypropertychanged) implementation guide could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Observable Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `List`

then all you have to do is manipulate this list as you want and it will automatically notify the UI with the changes